# div float left bug in google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I`ve got a structure of menu in HTML:

```
<div id="menu_box">
        <a title="" class="menu_item_rfc"
             href="/main/menu/1">   
            <div class="menu_item">
                bla bla bla
            </div>  
        </a>
        <a title="" class="menu_item_rfc"
             href="/main/menu/2">   
            <div class="menu_item">
                bla bla bla
            </div>  
        </a>
        <a title="" class="menu_item_rfc"
             href="/main/menu/3">   
            <div class="menu_item">
                bla bla bla
            </div>  
        </a>
    <div id="search_box">
        <form id="search_form" action="" method="post">
            <div style="float:left;padding:4px 0 0 0;">
                <input id="search" type="text" value="поиск товара" name="search"/>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left;padding:4px 0 0 0;">
                <div id="search_btn"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
#menu_box {
    display: table;
    /*margin:20px auto;*/
    width:715px;
    border:1px solid #efefef;
    -moz-border-radius-left:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;  
    margin: 23px 0 0 0;
    background-color:#efefef;
    float:right;
}
.menu_item {
    display: table-cell;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:7px 15px;
    height:18px;
    background-color:#fff;
    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #ddd 100%);

    /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #ddd 100%);

    /* Opera */ 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #ddd 100%);

    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #ddd));

    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #ddd 100%);

    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #ddd 100%);    
}
#search_box {
    display: table-cell;
    float:left;
    height:32px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

As U can see all elements in a menu_box floated left and menu_box is fixed by width.

The problem is that the last div, even if that was just a menu_item, drops down when resizing browser Ctrl+, Ctrl-, but on Ctrl0 dimensions it is ok.
A lot of users unconsciously use that dims +-.
This problem appears only in Chrome, in FF, Safari, EI it is ok.
How can I solve this matter? May be someone face that problem.
Thx in advance.

Example:[image: menu screen shot]

PS I don't think this is an anchor problem, I mean anchor wrapping the div menu_item.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's due to the way the browser is calculating the box.

Read about the [box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp), and using [border-box](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/). That should solve your problem.

If not, I'd have to see the code. Perhaps upload it to JSFiddle?

Comment: Thx, but `* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }` didn`t work for me.